# how to filter a birthday in Feb in an array using lambda in C#

Tags: c#, filter, lambda

I have an array of birthday

```
a {5-2-1991, 5-3-1991}
```

I want to use lambda in C# to filter the birthday which in February

I've tried

```
DateTime[] b = a.Where(x => x.Month == 2).ToArray();
```

also tried

```
DateTime[] b = a.Where(x => x.Month = 2).ToArray();
```

but nothing work.

/////////////////UPDATE//////////////////////

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Nhap so luong phan tu trong mang a: ");
            int an = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            DateTime[] a = new DateTime[an];
            for (int i = 0; i < an; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Nhap phan tu thu " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                a[i] = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            //a
            List<DateTime> blist = new List<DateTime>();

            foreach (DateTime ngaysinh in a)
            {
                if (ngaysinh.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    blist.Add(ngaysinh);
                }
            }
            DateTime[] b = blist.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Cac ngay sinh vao CN cua mang a la: ");
            foreach (DateTime ngaysinh in b) Console.WriteLine(ngaysinh.ToString("d"));

            //b
            Console.WriteLine("Cac ngay sinh tuong ung mang a: ");
            int[] c = new int[an];
            for (int i = 0; i < an; i++)
            {
                c[i] = DateTime.Today.Year - a[i].Year;
                Console.WriteLine(c[i]);
            }

            //c
            var mangngay = a.Where(ngay => ngay.Month == 2).ToArray().OrderBy(x => x.Year);
            foreach (DateTime phantu in mangngay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(phantu);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

when I use

```
DateTime[] mangngay = a.Where(ngay => ngay.Month == 2).ToArray().OrderBy(x => x.Year);
```

It show the error

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.DateTime>' to 'System.DateTime[]'
```

But when I change TO

```
var mangngay = a.Where(ngay => ngay.Month == 2).ToArray().OrderBy(x => x.Year);
```

The code works perfectly. Can anyone explain me why?

Thank you.

Comment: Your array looks like integers to me (e.g. 5-2-1991 = -1988)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example :

```
DateTime[] a = new DateTime[]{new DateTime(2014, 2, 1), new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), };
var dates = a.Where(date => date.Month == 2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What type is that array? Are they actually `DateTime` values? If so, the first line you tried should work. You'll just have to make sure your array is initialized like this:

```
DateTime[] a = new[] { DateTime.Parse("5/2/1991"), DateTime.Parse("5/3/1991") };
```

Assuming your culture is set up to have the day of the month precede the month itself.